# How can I join (Shift+J) the next N words to current line, instead of the entire line?

Tags: vim, vi

Sometimes when doing things like reformatting a block comment in code, I find I need to move words up one line. In the below example say I want to move the word 'hopefully' to the first line. Usually I use `Shift+J` to join the entire line, move my cursor to after the word 'hopefully' and then press `Enter` to move the remainder of the line back down.

```
/* Line 1 of some large comment block,
   hopefully it contains well written documentation. I'd
   now like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

Even though it doesn't seem like much, the sequence of commands I'm currently doing gets tedious if a lot of lines need this sort of change. Is there a variation of the Join command that can only do it for the first N words in the next line? Something like "2wJ" to join the first two words of the next line would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Bad News**

I'm not sure something like what you suggest exists, although it definitely could - Vim surprises me every day.  I'm sure someone on SO knows.

**The Good News**

There's a better way to achieve what you want! Or, what I *think* you want.  You can tell Vim to perform a formatting operation on a given region of text.  All you have to do is set `textwidth` to the maximum width you'd like, then use `gq{motion}` to format the text that `{motion}` moves over.  For your example:

```
/* Line 1 of some large comment block,
   hopefully it contains well written documentation. I'd
   now like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

You would simply set a reasonable `textwidth` – here it looks like you're going for about 50 – and then format the comment.  Put your cursor on the first `/`, and

```
:set textwidth=50
gq%
```

**The Catch**

*But wait,* you say, *that didn't work!*

Whoops.  You're right.  What appears to have happened here is that Vim doesn't understand this format.  When I followed my own instructions, I saw this, though your mileage may vary:

```
/* Line 1 of some large comment block,
   hopefully it contains well written 
documentation. I'd now like 'hopefully' to be on 
the first line.
 */
```

That doesn't look right, and it isn't.  However, if I reformat your block comment to something that Vim recognizes (this is how I write my block comments anyways), like so:

```
/* 
 * Line 1 of some large comment block,
 * hopefully it contains well written documentation. I'd
 * now like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

and then I `gq%` (with `textwidth` still 50) I get:

```
/* 
 * Line 1 of some large comment block, hopefully 
 * it contains well written documentation. I'd now 
 * like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

That seems like it worked.  The word "now" was moved from the third line to the second, too, but I'd argue that that was a good decision on Vim's part.  One more note: if you don't like those leading `*`s, Vim will also do a good job with this format:

```
/* 
   Line 1 of some large comment block,
   hopefully it contains well written documentation. I'd
   now like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

When I `gq%` this, I get:

```
/* 
   Line 1 of some large comment block, hopefully 
it contains well written documentation. I'd now 
like 'hopefully' to be on the first line.
 */
```

A little funny, but it makes sense.  Looks more like a paragraph to me.  Hopefully something in here is useful.

**Edit:**

As progo handily mentioned in another answer, you can use `gqap` everywhere I've used `gq%` above.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you (and progo). Since what I was really trying to do was reformat a block of text, these solutions are WAY better than reformatting each line individually! (And my comments actually have a leading * on each line too, I just left that out for ease of describing my current way of doing it. Didn't feel like mentioning that I delete the * from the joined line as well.)

Answer (score 1):

How about letting vim handle the formatting of your comment blocks. `gqap` does one paragraph. If it doesn't do what you want out of the box, check out `:help 'fo` (format options) and especially `:help 'fo-table`. For instance, setting `:set fo+=j` might help with those C blocks (remove comment leader automatically when joining lines.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing built-in in vim.

think about `2wJ`, vim will think you want to move two words forwardly, and then Join.

You could either do it in your old way: `J2elr<cr>` or create a mapping, receive the number of words you want to join as parameter, to make it easier:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>jw 'J' . nr2char(getchar()) . 'elr<CR>'
```

so with this mapping, if you press `<leader>jw`, vim waits for a further input key, which is the number of words you want to "join". **however this is not a perfect solution**, because:

- it won't work if you want to join more than 9 words. the mapping expects single char.
- it could do something completely unexpected, for example, if you press `d`, the two words would be removed.
- if you want to make a better solution, you could write a function and make a mapping to call that. if it is worth to do.

I prefer to join and cut manually.